# Create path to file under 64-bit %programfiles% from 32-bit process

Tags: c#, .net

I have a process that runs as 32-bits regardless of the architecture.  In it, I want to be able to spawn a process from the 64-bit program files menu (e.g. `c:\program files` instead of `c:\program files (x86)\`).

I tried using `System.Environment.GetFolderPath`, but for a 32 bit process, both `SpecialFolders.ProgramFiles` and `SpecialFolders.ProgramFilesX86` returned the x86 folder.  Ditto trying to use `System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%programfiles%")`.

Instead I put together this mess:

```
Path.Combine(System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%systemdrive%") + @"\", @"Program Files\...");
```

The Path.Combine seems pretty useless since I've already put every '\' in there, so I simplified it to:

```
System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%systemdrive%") + @"\Program Files\...";
```

In my environment(s), the program files folder is always on the system drive, but the system drive has varying drive letters.  Is there any better way to write this?

Comment: Is there a reason why iy needs to be in `\Program Files\\` instead of `\Program Files (x86)\\`?

Comment: @JamesKhoury, I'm trying to launch an app that's installed separately from mine.  It only installs to `Program Files`.

Comment: I'd suggest a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916713/how-can-i-get-another-applications-installation-path-programmatically ... I've not tried it but the answers seem to suggest searching the registry for it. Specifically: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`

Answer (score 7):

In the end, I made a slight simplification and ended up with:

```
System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%systemdrive%\Program Files\...")
```